# Angular with nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have created an simple app with angular and node js but when i run this app it's through a error like this "http://localhost:8080/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)",

Here My Code :

### Index.html

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<div ng-app="myModule">
<h1>Form Validation Sample:Password and Repeat should be equals</h1>

    <form name="validatedForm" novalidate>
        <p><label>Username: </label><input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"
                required ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" size="20"/></p>
        <p><label>Password: </label><input type="text" name="password" ng-model="password1"/></p>

        <p><button ng-disabled="validatedForm.$invalid">Save</button></p>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- controller -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

### Server.js

```js
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();       
var http = require('http');

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile( __dirname + "/public/" + "index.html" ); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
app.listen(8080);

console.log('Server Start'+__dirname);
```

So any one help me to give any idea to resolve this error and how to publish the app to production server or how to publish this app to online and how to run this app?

Comment: The URL is supposed to be http://localhost:8080/index.html right ?

Comment: URL should be [http://localhost:8080/](http://localhost:8080/index.html) as you are listening for all get requests `/` not `index.html`

Comment: Try this `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="app.js"></script>`;

Answer (score 2):

You're not serving up anything except the html file, so the javascript files used by your html file won't get loaded. Uncomment the `express.static()` middleware.

Comment: Do you have `app.js` in your `public/` directory? Do you also have `js/angular.min.js` in your `public/` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your Http server only show html files.

Here is an good example http://blog.modulus.io/build-your-first-http-server-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Try this code for running the angular js file using node , and install path and express .